# Anaconda will not update ipython version

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython

I am trying to upgrade ipython using Anaconda and the conda terminal, but can't get the latest version to actually install.

I completely uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda, but am getting the same problem. I am working inside a newly-created virtual environment.

When I look for ipython in Anaconda Navigator, I see that 8.12.2 is installed (the version I want).

However when I start Spyder, it shows Spyder is using ipython=8.8 (which is incompatible).

So, I opened a Anaconda terminal, activated my new virtual environment, and typed "ipython --version" and it returns 8.8.

I've tried upgrading to 8.12.2 using both `conda install -c anaconda "ipython>=8.12"` and `conda install "ipython=8.12"`, both of which appeared to execute without problem. However when I run `ipython --version`, it still returns 8.8.

EDIT 1: when I open the `pkgs` folder to see which versions of ipython are installed, 8.8 is not present.

EDIT 2: `conda update ipython` did not work either.

EDIT 3: Running `pip show ipython` returns version 8.8. This suggests Anaconda is using the pip installed version of ipython instead of the conda version.

Does anyone know how to point Anaconda to the conda version and not the pip version? Or should I just update ipython using pip?

Thanks!

See below for screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OP answering for anyone else who may find this post because they have a similar problem.

From [this](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-avoid-installing-packages-with-pip-in-an-anaconda-environment/#:%7E:text=Using%20pip%20in%20an%20Anaconda%20environment%20can%20lead%20to%20dependency,incompatible%20versions%20of%20packages%20installed.) blog post, I read this:

> If you absolutely need to use both conda and pip in the same environment, you should install all conda packages first, and then use pip to install any remaining packages. This is because conda is aware of pip, but pip is not aware of conda.

A while ago I installed python 3.11 on my computer, outside of Anaconda. It created the `C:\Users\gbilley\AppData\Roaming\Python\` folder and populated it with packages, including ipython.

Anaconda was grabbing this version of ipython and ignoring the version installed in the Anaconda environment.

This problem was solved by deleting the `C:\Users\gbilley\AppData\Roaming\Python\` folder. I had no reason to keep Python installed outside of Anaconda, and felt it would be best to remove it entirely to avoid other possible conflicts. I suspect just deleting `site-packages\ipython` would have solved this problem as well.